# How to convert this activity to fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, fragment

I am trying to convert my activities into fragments, And I get a few errors can somebody point out to me where I am going wrong and how to fix it
I will show you the code where the errors occur but first the errors

firstly `getApplicationContext` `getContentResolver` and `RESULT_OK` gets a "cannot resolve method" errors

secondly, UploadFrag.this gets the wrong argument error

The Fragment is of an activity where you select an image and upload it to my work server

```java
package com.smartpractice.myapplication;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.provider.OpenableColumns;
import android.util.Base64;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;

import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;


import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Objects;

public class UploadFrag extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

public static final String UPLOAD_URL = "https://www.smsjsjjsjs.co.za/files-upload-ruben.asp?MyForm=Yes";
public static final String UPLOAD_KEY = "image";

private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;

private Button buttonChoose;
private Button buttonUpload;

private ImageView imageView;
private Bitmap bitmap;
private Uri filePath;

@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_upload, container, false);
}
@Override
public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        init();
        }
        private void init(){
        buttonChoose = getView().findViewById(R.id.btnChoose);
        buttonUpload = getView().findViewById(R.id.btnUpload);

        imageView = getView().findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        buttonChoose.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonUpload.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
private void showFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
        }
```

**Error Cannot resolve Symbol on RESULT_OK
and cannot resolve method on getContentResolver**

```java
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode ==* RESULT_OK* && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        filePath = data.getData();
        try {
        bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(*getContentResolver()*, filePath);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
 }
public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        return Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        }

private void uploadImage(){
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
class UploadImage extends AsyncTask<Bitmap,Void,String> {
    private ProgressDialog loading;
    private RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
```

**error UploadFrag.this gets 1st wrong argument type**

```java
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    loading = ProgressDialog.show(*UploadFrag.this,* "Uploading Image", "Please wait...",true,true);
}
```

**Error getApplicationContext cannot resolve method**

```java
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        loading.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(*getApplicationContext()*,s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @RequiresApi(api=Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Bitmap... params) {
        Bitmap bitmap = params[0];
        String uploadImage = getStringImage(bitmap);

        HashMap<String,String> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put(UPLOAD_KEY, uploadImage);
        data.put("name",getFileName(filePath));

        return rh.postRequest(UPLOAD_URL,data);
    }
}

    UploadImage ui = new UploadImage();
        ui.execute(bitmap);
                }
```

**error UploadFrag.this gets 2nd wrong argument type and cannot resolve method on makeText**

```java
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == buttonChoose) {
        showFileChooser();
        }
        if(v == buttonUpload){
        if(filePath!=null) {
        uploadImage();
        } else {
        *Toast.makeText(UploadFrag.this,"Select Image",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*
        }
     }
  }
```

**Error Cannot resolve method on getContentResolver**

```java
@RequiresApi(api=Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    String getFileName(Uri uri){
            String result = null;
            if (Objects.equals(uri.getScheme(), "content")) {
            try (Cursor cursor=*getContentResolver()*.query(uri, null, null, null, null)) {
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            result=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
            }
            }
            }
            if (result == null) {
            result = uri.getPath();
            assert result != null;
            int cut = result.lastIndexOf('/');
            if (cut != -1) {
            result = result.substring(cut + 1);
            }
            }
            return result;
            }
    }
```

Comment: In fragment as a context use _getActivity()_

Comment: too many questions in a single question. In general, activity has some methods that fragment does not have (`getApplicationContext` for example). Use `getActivity.getApplicationContext()` for example instead. same with `getContentResolver`. Also as for the `this` argument is becaus the method you are trying to use it in wants not just any `this`, but an object of some specific type, which fragment is not, but Activity is.

Comment: @Piyush Thank you, It seems like it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your error like below

```
getApplicationContext() with getActivity().getApplicationContext()

getContentResolver() with getActivity().getContentResolver()

 RESULT_OK with getActivity().RESULT_OK

 UploadFrag.this  replace with getActivity();
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getActivity()` for context in Fragment as @Piyush said.

You can use it like this ;

```
 getActivity().getContentResolver();
 getActivity().getApplicationContext 
 getActivity().RESULT_OK
```

Answer (score 0):

Fragments are fundamentally different from activities. In example you have provided there are a few activities, you open some to get result and pass around data and results.

In fragments you have one parent activity and can "swap content". You can have a fragment object unlike with activities. So there is no need for some methods like `onActivityResult`

But there are situations when you need to have some methods from activity. In that case just call `getActivity()` to get it. So for instance `getApplicationContext()` would become `getActivity().getApplicationContext()`